# Determine maximum bitrate supported to record videos

Tags: android, xamarin, record, mediarecorder, bitrate

Currently my bitrate is hardcoded to ~2mb/s. I want to set it to the maximum bitrate supported by the device, but I'm not sure how to check it.

Here's part of my code if it helps:

```
  MyRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // ...
        MyRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
        MyRecorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate("2000000"); 
    // ...
```

How do I check what is the maximum supported rate or what is the recommended bitrate for recording High Quality videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this :

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.High);//Quality level corresponding to the highest available resolution.
var targetVideoBitRate = camcorderProfile.VideoBitRate;
mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(targetVideoBitRate);
```

the more information you could refer to [CamcorderProfile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html)